# Get attached image ID when publishing post

Tags: wordpress

I want to get attached image id when a post is published. I am using following code:-

```
function my_function($post_id){
    echo $imgId = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ); die;
    return $post_id;
}
add_filter('publish_post', 'my_function');
```

Its not giving the Image ID.
When I edit and save an existing post then it returns image ID.

Please help.......

Comment: are you trying to get feature image id?

Comment: @anstrangel0ver yea...

Comment: try using `global $post` and `$post->id`

Comment: i can get the id $imgId with some value while publishing the new post  may be some thing is not right there

Comment: Thank you all for help. I got the Image ID using `$_POST['wpuf_featured_img']`

Comment: Why are you using $_POST to get the featured image?

Comment: @SMacFadyen What's wrong in it?

Comment: It's insecure, maybe there is an exploit? Use internal classes that WordPress provides.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get the featured image.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $alt_text = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large');  
    $image_url = $image_url[0];
 }
```